# How can I make Windows' system tray two rows instead of one?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, notification-area

My taskbar has two rows. First is the Quick Launch, second is for applications.

But my system trays is showing the icons only in one row, which is taking too much space. Is there any possibility to force them to appear in two rows?

This is how it looks now:

[image]

I'd like something like this:

[image]

Comment: In Windows 7 dragging the top of taskbar will make it two rows. Does this not also work in Windows 10? (Make sure the taskbar is not locked).

Comment: It works. I pulled up to create the 3rd row, then it arranged it to 2 rows, then I moved back to two rows, and it keeped the 2 rows. Add it as an anaswer, and I'll accept it. (After this, please comment here, you did it, to make sure, I've get the notification).

Comment: Answer has been added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### How can I make my System Tray icons occupy two rows?

1. First make sure that your taskbar is [not locked](http://www.howtogeek.com/225568/how-to-configure-and-customize-the-taskbar-in-windows-10/).
2. Now you can drag the top of the  taskbar to resize it.
3. This will increase the number of row used by the System Tray icons.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Note:

- Screenshots are for Windows 7

Comment: I can verify that this solution works perfectly also for Windows 10.

Comment: it works for any Windows version with a taskbar