# How to put the notification area in multiline mode?

Tags: taskbar, autohotkey, gui, desktop-customization, windows-server-2016

A couple of days ago the taskbar glitched (I actually use an AHK script to toggle its visibility) and I was left with a rather curious layout: a single-size taskbar with a wrapped notification area.

My goal here is to reproduce it somehow since i really like the notification area to be multiline and I always found dumb to have it on a single line, but I want the taskbar to be one row high with big icons, like the screenshot below.

[image]

It's not simulated. All notification icons seemed to work perfectly.

For aesthetic reasons I am aiming for two rows of notification area instead of the three shown above.

This is windows 10 (server 2016, actually but I doubt it changes anything).

**TL;DR**: I want my taskbar to match the screenshot.

## About the glitch

Let's start from the beginning. Some months ago, the windows taskbar started to rndomly stay visibile during full-screen mode (usually the browser/youtube or other media players). A restart of Explorer could fix that (not really since I would lose the spotify icon * facepalm *) but I still don't know why thas happened.

So, as a workaround I wrote a program to toggle the taskbar at the press of a button on the keyboard.

It finds the handle of the taskbar (class `Shell_TrayWnd`) and hides or shows it by using the AutoitX library.

Now, I believe that the frequent hiding and showing the taskbar interacted with the previous taskbar root problem and the fact I usualy hibernate my pc (maybe long time stability may be an issue for `explorer.exe`), resulting in the above screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Windows' system tray two rows instead of one?](https://superuser.com/questions/1050587/how-can-i-make-windows-system-tray-two-rows-instead-of-one)

Comment: Basically, set it to small icons, drag it to be 2 rows, make sure the taskbar items span both rows so it is one row, and it should produce the effect desired.

Comment: @LPChip I know that, but I wanted the taskbar to match my screenshot, tough. In the question I wrote "single-size taskbar": i meant having the taskbar one row high while having 2 rows of notifications area. I will now edit for clarity.

Comment: Yes, I know that. If you set it to 2 rows, and make the rows all 2 rows large, it will appear like one row, yet allow for 2 rows of notifications. Please understand that what you want is not natively possible without some kind of glitch.

Comment: Indeed I was thinking about manipulating the GUI with AHK

Comment: We would have to be able to understand fully what the glitch actually did, what triggered it and what it changed about the system before we could begin to reverse-engineer the problem to do it on purpose.